# Como transformar ponteiro em matriz

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, parâmetros

Estou fazendo um programa que transforma uma matriz em matriz transposta.
Eu estou usando 3 funções porque quero aprender como passar parâmetros de *arrays*.

A função `main()` chama a função `mValores` que pede ao usuário a quantidade de linhas e colunas da matriz e atribui o valor de cada elemento dessa matriz.

A função `mValores` por sua vez passa os parâmetros matriz, linhas, colunas; para a função `mTransposta` que recebe os locais dessas variáveis nos ponteiros `*A, *m, *n`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Tipo de matriz e seus valores
void mValores()
{

    //Declaração de variáveis
    int i, j; // i: Contador de linhas; j: contador de colunas;
    int linhas, colunas;

    //Definindo o tipo de matriz
    printf("\nDigite a quantidade de linhas: \n");
    scanf("%d", &linhas);
    printf("Digite a quantidade de Colunas: \n");
    scanf("%d", &colunas);

    int matriz [linhas] [colunas]; //Declaração do array bidimensional

    //Mostrando o tipo de matriz
    printf("Matriz do tipo: %dx%d ", linhas, colunas);
    if(linhas == colunas){

        printf("(Matriz quadrada).");

    }

    else if(linhas == 1 && colunas > 1){

        printf("(Matriz linha).");

    }

    else if(linhas > 1 && colunas == 1){

        printf("(Matriz coluna).");

    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < linhas; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < colunas; j++){

            printf("a%d%d ", i + 1, j + 1);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Atribuindo os valores da matriz
    printf("Digite os valores de: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < linhas; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < colunas; j++){

            printf("a%d%d ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz [i] [j]);

        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    //Mostrando os valores da matriz
    for(i = 0; i < linhas; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < colunas; j++){

                printf("%4d",matriz [i] [j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    mTransposta(matriz , linhas, colunas);

}

void main()
{

    //Declaração de variáveis
    char end;
    printf("\n***CALCULOS DE MATRIZES*** \n");

    do{

        printf("\nMatriz Transposta\n");

        mValores();

        printf("\nDigite 1 para sair ou digite qualquer outro numero para Continuar:\n");
        scanf("%d", &end);

    }while (end != 1);

}

void mTransposta(int *A, int *m, int *n) // A = matriz, m = linhas, n = colunas
{

    int i, j;

    *matrizTransposta [*m] [*n] = A;//Atribuição do local da variável matriz para variável matrizTransposta

    for(i = 0; i < *n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < *m; j++){

            printf("%4d",matrizTransposta [j] [i]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

O problema está na função `mTransposta`. Eu queria atribuir os valores que estão na variável matriz [linhas] [colunas] que fica na função `mValores()` à variável `matrizTransposta [*m] [*n]` que fica na função `mTransposta()` através do ponteiro `*A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas que eu consertei. Também está um pouco mal organizado por isso os comentários se fizeram necessários. Não organizei tudo, mas se fizer bem organizado não precisa de comentários.

Não tem como converter direto algo assim. Tem que receber uma matriz mesmo. Ou então tratar tudo como ponteiro e cuidar manualmente do acesso.

Esse transporte não é necessário nesta função, deixei porque pode ser um exercício. Mas exercícios deveriam se concentrar em uma funcionalidade apenas ou então fazer tudo certo, o que não ocorre aí.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Transposta(int linhas, int colunas, int matriz[][colunas]) {
    int matrizTransposta[colunas][colunas];
     for (int i = 0; i < colunas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < linhas; j++) matrizTransposta[i][j] = matriz[j][i];
        printf("\n");
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) printf("%4d", matrizTransposta[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void Valores() {
    int linhas, colunas;
    printf("\nDigite a quantidade de linhas: \n");
    scanf("%d", &linhas);
    printf("Digite a quantidade de Colunas: \n");
    scanf("%d", &colunas);
    int matriz[linhas][colunas];
    printf("Matriz do tipo: %dx%d ", linhas, colunas);
    if (linhas == colunas) printf("(Matriz quadrada).");
    else if (linhas == 1 && colunas > 1) printf("(Matriz linha).");
    else if(linhas > 1 && colunas == 1) printf("(Matriz coluna).");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) printf("a%d%d ", i + 1, j + 1);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Digite os valores de: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
            printf("a%d%d ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++) printf("%4d", matriz[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    Transposta(linhas, colunas, matriz);
}

int main() {
    int end;
    printf("\n***CALCULOS DE MATRIZES*** \n");
    do {
        printf("\nMatriz Transposta\n");
        Valores();
        printf("\nDigite 1 para sair ou digite qualquer outro numero para Continuar:\n");
        scanf("%d", &end);
    } while (end != 1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dGQakO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/drxcfoyx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MatrixParameter.c).

Comment: vc poderia me explicar pq colocou em mTransposta o parâmetro matriz [] [colunas]. pq não matriz [linhas] [colunas] ou matriz [linhas] []?

Comment: Poderia ter colocado as `linhas` também, as colunas são obrigatórias para o compilador poder fazer a conta do elemento a ser acessado, porque na verdade não é na memória não é uma matriz é um vetor organizado para parecer uma matriz.